# How to convert an AudioData to binary format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, binary

Hi I am trying to take an audio input via my microphone using `audio = r.listen(source)` where `r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()`.
I am trying to convert this audio-data instance `audio` to literally binary format i.e., 1's and 0's which I can store in a data structure say list so as to iterate or compare over it with equivalent other audio files or to do other operations like lcs etc.
Is this possible? How to go about this? If it is not possible what is the nearest possible way for my job? I need to find the lcs between the two audio i.e. most common part's length between them.
Please please help.